SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function unnest(jsonb) does not exist
I am using postgresql and I am trying to separate an array column with single values into different columns. The original column called fee_rule_id is like [98, 120, 133]. I want it to be column1 98, column2 120 column3 133.
I was using unnest function but I got error code 42883. Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
How do I fix that?
my query is like
select id
, modified
,unnest(fee_rule_id) as fee_id
from final_data

Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images.

There is no unnest() function for json, so the error is correct. Check the manual for how to handle json arrays: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

You can achieve this by converting the array to JSONB and then extract each element into separate columns using JSONB indexing and type casting. Hope this helps>>
SELECT 
    id,
    modified,
    (fee_rule_id->>0)::int AS column1,
    (fee_rule_id->>1)::int AS column2,
    (fee_rule_id->>2)::int AS column3
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        modified, 
        fee_rule_id::jsonb AS fee_rule_id 
    FROM 
        final_data
) subquery;


I have a jsonb column in db that is List of int in c#. I wanted to add a condition for contains of an int number for that column. Finally this condition worked for me :
var num = 123;
var query = ...
&& EF.Functions.JsonContains(cartable.PersonCodes, new List<int> { num } // this

